# How to make service for Play Pause of music Player

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

Here is my code which is play song from the resources folder and now I am stuck with service so please help me.....

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mHandler=new Handler();

    seekBar=findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

    mp=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.ed);
    final int Duration=mp.getDuration();
```

> Media Player Prepared Listener.....

```
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
            updateSeekBar();
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

> Runnable Thread for Seekbar.....

```
    runnable=new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
   updateSeekBar();
     }
};
```

> Phone State Listener for Incoming and Outgoing Calls.....

```
    PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                mp.pause();
            } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
               mp.start();
            } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                mp.pause();
            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    };
    TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) 
      getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     if(mgr != null) {
        mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, 
         PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }

}
```

> Seek Bar Update Method....

```
private void updateSeekBar() {
    seekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
    mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);

}

}
```

> Now, it's my service code.......

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

public class MyMusicService extends Service {
```

> On Create method of service....

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}
```

> On start method of service....

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

> On Destroy method of service....

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

> Binder of Service.....

```
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Where is your service codes?

Answer (score 2):

see i have added the code of service which is work for me.

you can try this code for your need

```
package com.example.musicplayer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;

/*
 * This is demo code to accompany the Mobiletuts+ series:
 * Android SDK: Creating a Music Player
 * 
 */

public class MusicService extends Service implements 
MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,
MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

    //media player
    private MediaPlayer player;
    //song list
    private ArrayList<Song> songs;
    //current position
    private int songPosn;
    //binder
    private final IBinder musicBind = new MusicBinder();
    //title of current song
    private String songTitle="";
    //notification id
    private static final int NOTIFY_ID=1;
    //shuffle flag and random
    private boolean shuffle=false;
    private Random rand;

    public void onCreate(){
        //create the service
        super.onCreate();
        //initialize position
        songPosn=0;
        //random
        rand=new Random();
        //create player
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        //initialize
        initMusicPlayer();
    }

    public void initMusicPlayer(){
        //set player properties
        player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), 
                PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        //set listeners
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
    }

    //pass song list
    public void setList(ArrayList<Song> theSongs){
        songs=theSongs;
    }

    //binder
    public class MusicBinder extends Binder {
        MusicService getService() { 
            return MusicService.this;
        }
    }

    //activity will bind to service
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return musicBind;
    }

    //release resources when unbind
    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent){
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        return false;
    }

    //play a song
    public void playSong(){
        //play
        player.reset();
        //get song
        Song playSong = songs.get(songPosn);
        //get title
        songTitle=playSong.getTitle();
        //get id
        long currSong = playSong.getID();
        //set uri
        Uri trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                currSong);
        //set the data source
        try{ 
            player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), trackUri);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);
        }
        player.prepareAsync(); 
    }

    //set the song
    public void setSong(int songIndex){
        songPosn=songIndex; 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //check if playback has reached the end of a track
        if(player.getCurrentPosition()>0){
            mp.reset();
            playNext();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        Log.v("MUSIC PLAYER", "Playback Error");
        mp.reset();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //start playback
        mp.start();
        //notification
        Intent notIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);

        builder.setContentIntent(pendInt)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play)
        .setTicker(songTitle)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setContentTitle("Playing")
        .setContentText(songTitle);
        Notification not = builder.build();
        startForeground(NOTIFY_ID, not);
    }

    //playback methods
    public int getPosn(){
        return player.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    public int getDur(){
        return player.getDuration();
    }

    public boolean isPng(){
        return player.isPlaying();
    }

    public void pausePlayer(){
        player.pause();
    }

    public void seek(int posn){
        player.seekTo(posn);
    }

    public void go(){
        player.start();
    }

    //skip to previous track
    public void playPrev(){
        songPosn--;
        if(songPosn<0) songPosn=songs.size()-1;
        playSong();
    }

    //skip to next
    public void playNext(){
        if(shuffle){
            int newSong = songPosn;
            while(newSong==songPosn){
                newSong=rand.nextInt(songs.size());
            }
            songPosn=newSong;
        }
        else{
            songPosn++;
            if(songPosn>=songs.size()) songPosn=0;
        }
        playSong();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopForeground(true);
    }

    //toggle shuffle
    public void setShuffle(){
        if(shuffle) shuffle=false;
        else shuffle=true;
    }

}
```

OR

if you want to learn from scratch then

follow this link to learn and create your self too.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-project-setup--mobile-22764

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-song-playback--mobile-22778

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-user-controls--mobile-22787

i hope it helps you.

thanks.

Comment: thanks for your answer but is there any way to communicate between service class and my song playing activity. Like tap on next button from notification then click on notification so UI shows me current song.........not the last one

Comment: do you know about service class or not

Comment: go hear :- https://github.com/Rj-Innocent-Coder/android-music-player   and learn your self  there is whole music player project.

Comment: the code of music player on github is incomplete but thanks for your contribution user dev_ramiz_1702

Comment: ya its developed by me and my friends.

Comment: and here also i add service file too.